# How to add Azure AD Authentication to existing .NET MVC Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have an existing .NET MVC Web application which is using Windows Authentication. As we are migrating the project from On-Premise to Azure, there is a necessity of updating the application to use Azure AD Authentication. I was trying to use Connected Services using VS 2019, but not able to find Azure AD Authentication related service. Can anyone please share the process to add Azure AD to existing app?

[image]

Comment: Which guide are you following? You shouldn't need to go to "Connected Services." You can publish the app by going to Solution Explorer > Publish > Azure after you have configured the App Service and resource group. Then you can register the application and add the authentication. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=netcore31&pivots=development-environment-vs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service

Comment: There is also a sample for this on Github:https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

**1)** I tried with creating new ASP .NET MVC application project in Visual studio 2019 .click on the **Change** Under the **Authentication**

[image]

**2)** Select **Work or School Accounts**  .

[image]

**3)** you can enter a domain name and also select the **Read directory data** option as desired. Developers typically include this option.

[image]

**Solution 2:**

**1)**  Select the **Project > Add Connected Service**... menu command, or double-click the **Connected Services node** found under the project in Solution Explorer

**2)**  On the Connected Services page, select **Authentication with Azure Active Directory**

[image]

**3)**  On the Introduction page, select **Next**. If you see errors on this page, refer to [Diagnosing errors with the Azure Active Directory Connected Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-error)

[image]

**4)** On the **Single-Sign On page**, select a **domain** from the Domain drop-down list. The list contains all domains accessible by the accounts listed in the Account Settings dialog of Visual Studio **(File > Account Settings...)**. As an alternative, you can enter a domain name if you don’t find the one you’re looking for, such as mydomain.onmicrosoft.com. You can choose the option to create an Azure Active Directory app or use the settings from an existing Azure Active Directory app. Select **Next** when done.

[image]

**5)** On the Directory Access page, select the **Read directory data option** as desired. Developers typically include this option.

[image]

**6)** Select **Finish** to start modifications to your project to enable Azure AD authentication

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-add-connected-service)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details with screenshots. The problem is i am not able to see Configure Azure AD Authentication under Connected Services. I have updated VS 2019 with latest version as well (Visual Studio Professional 2019 16.11.1)

Comment: I have the same issue myself. The Configure Azure AD Authentication does not display as an option. Only OpenAPI is available for me. Please advise